# Python SQL fetchall() returns nothing

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch data from my table with this command:

```
SELECT userPassword FROM Coins.UserInfo WHERE username = 'Hello';
```

I have run this in the SQL runner on the database website, and it works fine. However, when I run it through python:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT userPassword FROM Coins.UserInfo WHERE username = 'Hello';")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

It returns an empty list.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show the full code, how you set up the cursor and the connection please.

Comment: Cross check you db name, user etc.

Comment: Don't you think `Coins.UserInfo` should have been`UsereInfo` instead?

Comment: I haven't selected the table as I don't know how with python SQL - it still works though

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior if there is no user named "Hello".

Comment: I have fixed the problem (I used fetchall() twice) - there was a user called Hello

Comment: ah!  That would do it! Glad you found the issue.